# Disqus installed manually, only shows disqus_thread iframe with 1px !important

Tags: disqus

Implementing Disqus manually gives me only a 1px iframe. Removing that line from the developer tools shows Disqus. Can't find any people having run into the same problem using Google.

There is no error shown in the console.

This is the code it will eventually show:

```
<iframe 
  id="dsq-app1" 
  name="dsq-app1" 
  allowtransparency="true" 
  frameborder="0" 
  scrolling="no" 
  tabindex="0" 
  title="Disqus" 
  width="100%" 
  src="url.html&amp;s_o=default" 
  style="
    width: 1px !important; /* Here it's defined by default */
    min-width: 100% !important; 
    border: none !important; 
    overflow: hidden !important; 
    height: 933px !important;" 
  horizontalscrolling="no" 
  verticalscrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

It's compiled and in a iframe so I don't have any control over it, setting the width to 100% will be overwritten by the iframe

Perhaps someone had this problem also?

Answer (score 0):

Add parent div and set width 100% to it

```
<div id="disqus_thread_parent">
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
</div
```

CSS

```
#disqus_thread_parent{ width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem using this plugin in WordPress, and I found the cause in my env. The property `display:flex` caused that problem, so I put this code,

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <iframe id="dsq-app*">...
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.main-content {
    display: block;
}
```

If you use grid layout, I believe this will help you.